# SQL Query to group ID overlap (via inner join) by month

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to find  a query that will give me the number of customers that have transacted with 2 different entities in the same month. In other words, customer_ids that transacted with company_a and company_b within the same month. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Extract(year FROM company_a_customers.transaction_date) 
       || Extract(month FROM company_a_customers.transaction_date) AS 
       payment_month, 
       Count(UNIQUE(company_a_customers.customer_id)) 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   my_table 
        WHERE  ( merchant_name LIKE '%company_a%' )) AS company_a_customers 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                   FROM   my_table 
                   WHERE  ( merchant_name = 'company_b' )) AS 
                  company_b_customers 
               ON company_a_customers.customer_id = 
                  company_b_customers.customer_id 
GROUP  BY Extract(year FROM company_a_customers.transaction_date) 
          || Extract(month FROM company_a_customers.transaction_date)
```

The problem is that this is giving me a running total of all customers that transacted with company A on a month-by-month basis who also *ever* transacted with company B.

If I whittle it down to a specific month, it will obviously give me the correct overlap, because the query is only getting IDs for that month:

```
SELECT Extract(year FROM company_a_customers.transaction_date) 
       || Extract(month FROM company_a_customers.transaction_date) AS 
       payment_month, 
       Count(UNIQUE(company_a_customers.customer_id)) 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   my_table 
        WHERE  ( merchant_name LIKE '%company_a%' ) 
               AND transaction_date >= '2017-06-01' 
               AND transaction_date <= '2017-06-30') AS company_a_customers 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                   FROM   my_table 
                   WHERE  ( merchant_name = 'company_b' ) 
                          AND transaction_date >= '2017-06-01' 
                          AND transaction_date <= '2017-06-30') AS 
                  company_b_customers 
               ON company_a_customers.customer_id = 
                  company_b_customers.customer_id 
GROUP  BY Extract(year FROM company_a_customers.transaction_date) 
          || Extract(month FROM company_a_customers.transaction_date)
```

How can I do this in one query to get monthly totals for customers who transacted with both companies within the given month?

Desired result: Output of second query, but for every month that is in the database. In other words:

January 2017: xx,xxx overlapping customers
February 2017: xx,xxx overlapping customers
March 2017: xx,xxx overlapping customers

Thanks very much.

Comment: Edit your question.  (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data.  (3) Provide desired results.

Comment: I've made the suggested edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply calculate year/month for both and then add it as a join-condition, but this is not very efficient as it might create a huge intermediate result.

You better check for each month/customer if there were transactions with both merchants using conditional aggregation. And then count by month:

```
SELECT payment_month, count(*)
FROM 
 (  SELECT Extract(year FROM transaction_date) 
           || Extract(month FROM transaction_date) AS payment_month, 
           customer_id
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  ( merchant_name LIKE '%company_a%' ) 
       OR  ( merchant_name = 'company_b' )
    GROUP  BY payment_month, 
           customer_id 
    -- both merchants within  the same months
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN merchant_name LIKE '%company_a%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
       AND SUM(CASE WHEN merchant_name = 'company_b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1
```

YOur `payment_month` calculation is to complicated (and the returned string is not nicely formatted).

To get year/month as string:

```
TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'YYYYMM')
```

as number:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) * 100
+ EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date)
```

or calculate the first of month:

```
TRUNC(transaction_date, 'mon')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get your desired results in one query just by counting the number of merchant_names per month per customer id. Using HAVING > 1 will show you only customers with transactions with both (or more if there are more matches for like '%company_a%').

```
SELECT
 EXTRACT(Year from transaction_date)||EXTRACT(Month from transaction_date) as payment_month
 ,customer_id
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT merchant_name) as CompanyCount
FROM my_table
WHERE transaction_date >= '2017-06-01' AND transaction_date <= '2017-06-30'
  AND (merchant_name = 'company_b' or merchant_name LIKE '%company_a%')
GROUP BY
  EXTRACT(Year from transaction_date)||EXTRACT(Month from transaction_date) 
 ,customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT merchant_name) > 1
```